# datetime in unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit-3.0

I am trying to test below method and i get funny dates.

```
public Pool AddPool(PoolDto poolDto, int createdByWho)
    {
        var pool = _mapper.Map<Pool>(poolDto);

        _mycontext.Pools.Add(pool);

        _mycontext.Save();
    }
```

this is my test

```
public void test_the_add_pool_method()
{
    var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US", true)).Date;

    var poolDto= new PoolDto
     {
         RequestorId = 1,
         ClientId = 1,
         Description = "Pool request",
         PoolStates = new List<PoolState>(),
         BookingDate = date,
         BookingFrom = date,
         BookingTo = date.AddDays(1)
     };

     service.AddPool(poolDto,1);

      Assert.That(Pools.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().RequestorId, Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().ClientId, Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().Description, Is.EqualTo("Pool request"));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingDate, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingFrom, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingTo, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date));
}
```

when i run the test it fails with this error Message:

```
Expected: 2018-03-20 00:00:00
  But was:  0001-01-01 00:00:00
```

i did not capture `0001-01-01 00:00:00` and it is very confusing where is that date come from. 
How can i find out the where abouts of the `0001-01-01 00:00:00` ??

Comment: Maybe, automapper does not map date properties?

Comment: I have `CreateMap<PoolDto, Pool>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BookingFrom, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap()` to handle the bookingFrom datetime

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Answer (score 1):

"0001-01-01 00:00:00" is the default value for a DateTime (`default(DateTime)`). It is the value that a DateTime will have if it has not been set to anything.

My guess would be that your mapper is not mapping that value across.

P.S. did you really want to `var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US", true)).Date;` (i.e. is that culture part relevant), or do you just not know that you could do `var date=DateTime.Today;`?

**UPDATE**
It's really hard to help you with more specific detail, since:

1. You haven't told us which line is throwing the assert failure (so we don't know which date it's complaining about)
2. We don't have the definition of Pool or PoolDto
3. We don't even know what type "_mapper" is (we're just guessing that it's an AutoMapper)

I'm assuming that `service.AddPool(PoolDto,1);` is a typo since PoolDto is a type - I expect that should be `service.AddPool(pool,1);`?

Also I would recommend against having tests where you just use "1" for multiple things. If your code has a bug in it, and the RequestorId is accidentally put in the ClientId field and vice versa, then this test will pass even though the code doesn't work. Similar problem if you use the same date for different fields.

Comment: Am I not setting it with `DateTime.Now` or the way i did with my `var date` Oh Yes I also tried `DateTime.Today`

Comment: @MohlalaStanley You are putting a value in a date variable, which is being use for two of the properties of a `PoolDto` and slightly modified for a third. That object is being passed to the method under test, which looks like it might be using automapper to map the values to a `Pool` object. That object is being added to a Pools property on a `context` variable we know nothing about. The test asserts things about a `Pools` variable that we know nothing about. I'm guessing it refers to the property with that name on the context. You still haven't answered my point 1.

Comment: Given the maping snippet you gave with Ignore with BookingFrom, I'm going to guess that this is the field which isn't being mapped. If you remove that ForMember clause, I'd guess it will start mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass pool to test not the PoolDto

```
public void test_the_add_pool_method()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-US", true)).Date;

    var pool = new PoolDto
     {
         RequestorId = 1,
         ClientId = 1,
         Description = "Pool request",
         PoolStates = new List<PoolState>(),
         BookingDate = date,
         BookingFrom = date,
         BookingTo = date.AddDays(1)
     };

     service.AddPool(PoolDto,1); //service.AddPool(pool ,1);

      Assert.That(Pools.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().RequestorId, Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().ClientId, Is.EqualTo(1));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().Description, Is.EqualTo("Pool request"));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingDate, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingFrom, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date));
      Assert.That(Pools.First().BookingTo, Is.EqualTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Date));
}
```

Comment: but `AddPool(PoolDto poolDto, int createdByWho)` want to get `poolDto` object i will try to change from the method then see how dat works. thanks

Comment: you are creating a PoolDto object with name pool  " var pool = new PoolDto" but while calling  the  service.AddPool you are sending  PoolDto  "service.AddPool(**PoolDto**,1) ". In this case PoolDtao will have default date value which is "0001-01-01 00:00:00".